# Dubious 'Int' vs 'Integer' handling in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, integer

Just for kicks, I wanted to see what would happen if I defined a function in Haskell as `Int -> Int`, knowing that it would overflow and have to return an `Integer`. Consider the following:

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

Now I know that if I run `factorial 50`, I'm going to get a number outside of the 'codomain' of `factorial`. Since Haskell is so strongly typed, I was hoping it would return an error. Instead GHCi returns a weird negative `Int`:

```
ghci> factorial 50
-3258495067890909184
```

And note that

```
ghci> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775808
```

since I'm running on 64 bit.

I find this behavior kind of scary: why doesn't Haskell raise an error? And why does `factorial 50` return a random negative number? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checking if an int went out of range every time a calculation is done on it would be completely absurd and destroy performance.  If you have a function that may go out of range use `Integer`.  Factorial is a appropriate time to do so because it creates large values so quickly.

Comment: I obviously knew that it was going to go out of range beforehand (did you read the post?). The question is why did I get a dubious negative number instead of, say, the upperbound of Int.

Comment: why would you expect it to return an `Integer`?  It's a valid `Int -> Int -> Int` and your answer, with `product` operating on `Int`, is `Int`.   Your answer is a very legal `Int`, by all definitions of `Int`.

Comment: It is, by the way, not a random negative number. It is precisely what one would expect (for 64-bit `Int`s on GHC), the remainder of `50!` modulo `2^64` in the range `-2^63` to `2^63-1`.

Comment: @JustinL. I didn't necessarily expect it to return an `Int`. All I knew is that it would overflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Int` type is defined as "A fixed-precision integer type with at least the range [-2^29 .. 2^29-1]." [0] The range varies by machine but you can find it with `minBound` and `maxBound`

The reason it overflows is that it's got a fixed amount of memory allocated for it. Imagine a simpler example - a positive integer in memory whose maximum value was 7 (stored as 3 bits in memory)

0 is represented as 000, in binary
1 is represented as 001
2 is represented as 010, etc.

Note how the bit math works: when you add 1, you either turn the smallest digit from 0 to 1, or you turn it from 1 to 0 and do the same operation on the next-most-significant digit.

So for example, `011 + 1` is `100`.

Now if you naievely (as Haskell does) perform this when there's *no* next-most-significant digit, then it just increments as usual, but "gets its head cut off." E.g. `111 + 1` becomes `000` instead of `1000`. This is what's happening with Haskell, except that <del>its lowest value (represented as a series of `0`s) is its lowest negative number.</del> it uses its "leftmost" bit to represent +/-. You'll need to do `(maxBound :: Int) + (maxBound :: Int) + 2` to get 0.

So similarly:

```
>  maxBound :: Int  
9223372036854775807  
>  (maxBound :: Int) + 1  
-9223372036854775808  
>  (maxBound :: Int) + 2  
-9223372036854775807  
>  let x = (maxBound :: Int) + 1 in x + x
0
```

Why "allow" this to happen? Simple - efficiency. It's much faster to not check for if there'll be an integer overflow. This is the reason that `Integer` exists - it's unbounded, for when you think you might overflow, but you pay a price in efficiency.

[0] http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Int.html

Comment: A minor point -- the system you are describing for signed ints (offset binary) is actually very uncommon in most CPU architectures.  The lowest negative number is actually usually `100...` on most modern architectures.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: The neat thing about two's complement is that it allows this "ring" structure to still exist.  Take the highest positive number, `0111`, and add one, and you get `1000`, the lowest negative number.  From then on you're counting up; at `1111`, you're at -1, and add one more and you get `0000` (zero).

Comment: @JustinL. Absolutly, I never heard that the lowest number is all null bits. This is probably a misconception of the poster. To check `shiftR (maxBound :: Int) 63` should give 0, not `minBound+1`.